# How to script vpncmd to batch command connect/disconnect?

Tags: windows, batch

Here is my **connect.bat**

-----BEGIN------

```
vpncmd localhost /client
accountconnect myConnectionName
```

-----END------

After executing **connect.bat**, here is the screen result:

```
Connected to VPN Client "localhost".

VPN Client>
```

**accountconnect myConnectionName** is not being executed.

How do I get **accountconnect myConnectionName** to run at the `VPN Client>` prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vpncmd` can use a file with commands as an input, using the `/IN:file` switch.

This is the approach i would use to automate things.

Something like :

```
vpncmd localhost /client /in:commands.txt
```

Then put your command in `commands.txt` :

```
accountconnect myConnectionName
```

---

If you only want to send one command, then `/IN` switch could be an overkill.

In this case you could use the `/CMD` switch instead, something like :

```
vpncmd localhost /client /CMD accountconnect myConnectionName
```

---

Further reading about command line parameters :

- https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.2_General_Usage_of_vpncmd#6.2.3_Command_Line_Parameters_When_Starting_a_vpncmd_Command

Comment: thanks! `/CMD` switch is working, one correction though, the double-quotes surrounding `"accountconnect myConnectionName"` is invalid. I had to remove them to have it run correctly.

Comment: @Level1Coder ok great ! so feel free to mark it as "answered" ! sorry for the extras double-quotes : as i don't use this utility myself i just wrote it "blindly" ;) I have corrected my answer

Answer (score -4):

This is a bash script written based on the following documentation
https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.2_General_Usage_of_vpncmd#6.2.3_Command_Line_Parameters_When_Starting_a_vpncmd_Command

```
#!/bin/bash
VPN_HOME=/usr/apps/vpnclient
NEW_IP=192.168.1.2
ACCOUNT_NAME=
function start(){

cd $VPN_HOME

sudo ./vpnclient start

./vpncmd localhost /client /CMD remoteenable
./vpncmd localhost /client /CMD accountconnect $ACCOUNT_NAME
#You can add your commands here

}

function stop(){
cd $VPN_HOME

sudo ./vpnclient stop
}
START="start"
STOP="stop"
HELP="help"

function help(){

 echo "#################################################################";      
 echo "#---------------------------Help--------------------------------#";      
 echo "#################################################################";     
 echo "./vpn-manger.sh command                                                  
 echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------";        
 echo "commands are $START , $STOP or $HELP"                                     
 echo "#################################################################";

}
function commands(){                                                              
       COMMAND=$1                                                                 
       case "${COMMAND,,}" in                                                     
                  "$START")       start;          ;;                                
                  "$STOP")        stop;           ;;                                
                  "$HELP")        help;           ;;                                       
                  *)              echo "Please Check your Command";    ;;                             
       esac                                                                            
}

commands $1;
```

Comment: This question has already been answered with an accepted answer. Also, you included `!/bin/bash` in your script - this question was about Windows. In the future, when posting code/scripts, please format accordingly.